# Tkinter code throws exception in latest ActivePython

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, tkinter, activepython

After installing ActivePython 2.7.10.12, when trying to create a Tkinter instance, I get the following error:

```
ActivePython 2.7.10.12 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 21 2015, 12:07:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Tkinter import Tk
>>> root = Tk()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1814, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, want
objects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
    C:/Python27/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/lib/tcl8.5 C:/library C:/library C:/
tcl8.5.18/library C:/tcl8.5.18/library



This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that worked for me. I copied 2 directories: `tcl8.5` and `tk8.5`, from `C:\Python27\tcl` to `C:\Python27\lib`, and then the code ran without any error.

Comment: Does MS Windows support symlinks?  When tcl/tk is updated, it will be updated in C:\Python27\tcl so your programs will still be using the old (copied) version (may or may not cause a problem).